# Do Freeform Events Fire From Control Panel?

Tags: control-panel, plugin-freeform, events

It appears to me that Freeform Submission events do not fire when editing events in the control panel. They certainly fire from a front-end submission.

That would make this statement in the documentation untrue. Emphasis added.

> Hook into Submission events to attach your own logic for when
>   submissions are being created, **edited** or deleted. [[1]](https://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v3/developer/submission-events.html)

Can someone smarter than me confirm or deny this, please?

Answer (score 1):

"Submissions" is referring to the submission  of a front end form. Not the Control Panel.

Comment: Thanks. This isn't very helpful, though. From my understanding **Submission** is an `element` Shouldn't matter. Maybe it does. Do you know of any events firing from the control panel then?